# How to rearrange text files into columns?

Tags: text, vim

I want to rearrange a text two text blocks into columns.

Consider the following example

```
line a1 
line a2
line a3 space
line a4

line b1 
line b2
line b3 
line b4
```

I would like to turn it into

```
# Col1         #Col2 
line a1        line b1 
line a2        line b2 
line a3 space  line b3 
line a4        line b4
```

I have looked into the `column` command which would require the lines to be in one line with a appropriate separator such as `line a1 & line b1`. Then I could just run `column -s"&" -t` (in vim).

Is there a more elegant way to do this? My preferred editor is vim so a solution based on vim would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `ctrl-v` enter column mode, select the first block press `d`
- same as `ctrl-v` select the 1st column in 2nd block, then press `I<space><space><Esc>`
- press `shift-p` to paste the 1st block in place
- press `ggd)` to remove the empty lines

It works like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. that is great. That helps a lot. By the way I am adding some lyrics for Meiko Kaji  and just like to have the Transliteration and translation side by side

Comment: Fun vim fact: you can force a motion to act block-wise. e.g. `$y<c-v>ip` would copy the first paragraph block-wise. See `:h force-motion`

Comment: @PeterRincker thx! I don't know it.. tried in my vim8.1, it works. but there is no help on `:h force-motion` I found out that it is `forced-motion`